# React Antd DatePicker with custom format for input and for display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd

I am currently using DatePicker Component of antd for displaying date but not able to customize the input format and display format.

Eg: user would type the date as mmddyy (112119) format, datePicker should display date as 2019-11-21.

Please find the sandbox link which I have tried by setting the value to datePicker but its getting overridden by format attribute

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-star-75qjq

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the `onOpenChange` event and change the `format` prop can do this.

```js
class DateInput extends React.Component {
  state = { isOpen: false };
  render() {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onChange}
        format={this.state.isOpen ? "MMDDYYYY" : "YYYY-MM-DD"}
        onOpenChange={status => {
          this.setState({ isOpen: status });
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[Codesandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-chandrasekhar-bhdjj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Keep the value the same while editing is a better user experience, different values between show and editing can be confusing.