# unable to display only year in react datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

> Here is my below custom component for datepicker with yyyy format

```
 return (
      <DatePickerWrapper disable={disable} >
        <DatePicker
          name={this.props.name}
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          showYearPicker
          dateFormat={"yyyy"}
        />
      </DatePickerWrapper>
    );
```

> I am still able to see it mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: which `<DatePicker />` lib you're using ? Can you share more about this ?

Comment: import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Antd DatePicker with custom format for input and for display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495987/react-antd-datepicker-with-custom-format-for-input-and-for-display)

Comment: no its different, i want Ui to display only Year

Comment: Your code should work fine. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-gauss-envsb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: your sample works fine, the returned value was in YYYY format. What would you expect this to be ?

Comment: sorry, I see what you meant. Maybe you only want the Year Picker ? There might be something wrong with the lib itself, the example on its site works but yours doesn't

Comment: I've just opened a bug report on the github. Hopefully this might be fixed soon. For the time being please bare with current Datepicker version

Comment: The `YearPicker` function is added yesterday (2020/5/6), so it is normal to have some bugs. I have tired on their demo, it's ok, but when deploy on codepen, I got the same problem.

Comment: Great news, author has updated this patch, you should upgrade your Datepicker to version 2.15.0

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly You want it to be displayed for only a year, but what Displayed as "Thu Jan 01 1970 07:00:01 GMT+0700".
You need to use .getFullYear() in onChange , this is the method I tried and it works.

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
    
    const [savedate, setSavedate] = useState();
    
    const <your component> = () => {
    
      return() {
            <DatePicker
               id="DatePicker"
               type="string"
               className="text-primary text-center"
               selected={birthYear}
               onChange={(date) => setSavedate(date.getFullYear())}
               showYearPicker
               dateFormat="yyyy"
               yearItemNumber={9}
               required
            />
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called **react-datetime**.We can pick only year using this library.
Install the library using this command:npm i react-datetime

Reference:https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime

Comment: This library is rather outdated. I'd suggest using something more recent of accepting year as a textbox with validation instead.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32915278)

Comment: @Andrii  & @Vojin Purić  thank you for all your valuable comments. Yes, the react-year-picker library is outdated. We can use `react-datetime` library with dateFormat="YYYY" in HTML tag. Like this,                                                    
            <Datetime
              dateFormat="YYYY"
              timeFormat={false}
            />

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way. I used 'react-datepicker' v4.11.0.

```
import moment from 'moment';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

const DatePickerComponent = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(1659312000000);

  const year = moment(startDate).format('yyyy');

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Date Picker</h1>
      <p>Selected year: {year}</p>
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        showYearPicker
        dateFormat="yyyy"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DatePickerComponent;
```

Find a working link here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tfzvsm?file=src%2Fdate-picker.jsx